# Can CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS be used for selective install?

Tags: cmake, installation

For my application, I created 4 components, and want to 'install' only the applications and their docs. According to https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackConfiguration, if in my config file I have the line

```
set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};ALL;/")
```

then all the four components are installed. If I use the component names instead like

```
set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};apps docs;/")
```

I receive a package with no component name appended, and it contains the top level requested directory but no files at all. If I provide only one component like

```
set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};apps;/")
```

the package name does not contain the name of the component, but the files are generated in their right position.

What do I wrong?

EDIT: Just to add more strange things:
For the ALL case 4 files with names `install_manifest_+comp name` are created. For the second case I have `install_manifest_apps docs.txt` of zero length, and for the third case I have `install_manifest_apps.txt`, with the right content.

It seems to me that the macro can only accept one argument which can be either ALL or a component name; this means it cannot be used to install a 2-component system.

Moreover: if I use a component name, `make package` only produces that one package, without appending the component name, but with the right content. Till now I guessed that `make install` and `make package` are independent.

Answer (score 2):

Set multiple values to CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS, one for each component you want to include:

```
set( CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};apps;/"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};docs;/"
)
```